# hackerrank doesn't accept my code but it prints the right result

Tags: php, arrays, while-loop

The code below is accepted by hackerrank

```
function staircase($n) {
    $d = 1;
    
    for($col=$n;$col>0;$col--){
        for($row = 1;$row <$col ;$row++ ){
            echo" ";
        }
    
        for($a = 0; $a <$d;$a++){
            echo"#";
        }
    
        $d++;
        echo"\n";
    }
}
```

This is my own code two code provide the same result but hackerrank don't accept my code. I want to know this reason

```
function staircase($n) {
    $x=1;
    $y=$n-1;
    
    while($x<=$n){
        while($y<$n){
            echo "#";
            $y++;
        }
    
        echo"\n";
        $x++;
        $y=$y-$x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't tag unrelated languages. Also, please format your code to make it readable.

Comment: Check if it is accepted for all the test cases, normally initial inputs would seem working

Comment: one code prints some spaces, the other one doesn't

Answer (score 1):

When you run your code in the HackerRank environment, you'll get this output:

[image]

But this is the output that the description of the task gives:

[image]

Notice the difference? The task description stresses this point:

> The staircase is **right-aligned**, composed of # symbols **and spaces**, and has a height **and width** of n = 6.

Your code does not print any spaces to align the hash symbols to the right.

Comment: Yes, I have fixed this code issue myself. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because both of your code output different .You can simply Check this 2 output

[First Code Accepted one](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xspsnrqv) (# output as right aligned )

[2nd Code](https://onecompiler.com/php/3xspsmbw3) (# output as left aligned )

Comment: Yes, I have fixed this code issue myself.thanks